# audio.play not working

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I get an "upvalue error" while I try to play audio in my app.
I have 2 files:

sound_board.lua

```
local enemy_damaged = audio.loadSound( "assets/audio/enemy_damaged.wav" )
local ouch = audio.loadSound( "assets/audio/ouch.wav" )
local pew = audio.loadSound( "assets/audio/pew.wav" )

local function playSound(to_play)
    audio.play( to_play )
end
```

level1.lua

```
local sound_board = require("sound_board")

-- some code
function fireSinglebullet()
    sound_board:playSound(pew) -- line 295

    -- some other code
end
```

At launch I get this error:

```
level1.lua:295: attempt to index upvalue 'sound_board' (a boolean value)
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefully what you return in `sound_board.lua` file. Error message tells that local variable `sound_board` in `level.lua` is a boolean value.

To get access to variables from another file use modules like that:

```
-- sound_board.lua

local M = {}

M.sounds = { 
  "enemy_damaged" = audio.loadSound( "assets/audio/enemy_damaged.wav" )
  "ouch" = audio.loadSound( "assets/audio/ouch.wav" )
  "pew" = audio.loadSound( "assets/audio/pew.wav" )
}

function M:playSound( to_play )

    audio.play( self.sounds[to_play] )

end

return M
```

and

```
-- level1.lua

local sound_board = require( "sound_board" )

-- some code
function fireSinglebullet()

    sound_board:playSound( "pew" ) -- line 295

    -- some other code
end
```

Read more: [External Modules in Corona](https://docs.coronalabs.com/tutorial/basics/externalModules/index.html)

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem and it also helped me to understand my mistake.

Note: you forgot the "," at the end of each of the table element